# For a program that takes a single number from a user, how can you test several values at once and then output them to a text file?

Tags: c, debugging, testing, file-io, io

I have written a fairly simple program in C that takes an input n and computes the n'th number in the fibonacci sequence. When this program runs, you enter a number on your keyboard, and it prints out the result. My question is, I can only manually test one input at a time, to check for bugs. How can I write a program to test several inputs at the same time, and output this to a readable text file?

I have tried writing a program to run these tests, but I don't know how to make the program use my function which is written in a separate file. I appear to be able to only test one at a time, and When I output the result to a text file, I cannot read the text file either, it is empty.

Comment: put the logic in a function and call it in a loop, write the output from the function to stdout or a file

Comment: I would have the program take its input from the command line (that is, `argv`) instead of the keyboard.  Then, I would write a [*shell script*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_script) to invoke the program multiple times, with the desired inputs.  (Granted, I'm a Unix weenie, so I'm always writing shell scripts.  If you've never used, or don't have access to, a command line, this approach won't be so easy.)

Comment: `for /F %i in (input.txt) do @(echo %i |my_program.exe)` where each line of `input.txt` contains a test

Comment: `for /F "tokens=1-2" %i in (input.txt) do @(echo %j && echo %i |my_program.exe)` where each line of `input.txt` contains a test value AND a correct result value

Comment: Since it is only for testing, use a label and `goto` to loop instead of exiting... Remove this when testing is complete. Can't help with the file output problem without seeing your code. (Sometimes it's best of conquer only one mountain at a time.)

Comment: OT: If your code works for the first 5-6 Fibonacci results, it should work for the rest up to the limit of the datatype you are using.

Comment: Show us the code that you have.

Comment: @Henry T,  "I have tried writing a program to run these tests" --> post that code.

Comment: If you are on linux: `seq 1000 | while read; do echo $REPLY | ./your_program >> output.txt`; done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to migrate your code to a function then call it in a loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>

long fib(long n) {
   // ...
}

int main() {
    long n = 2;
    for(long i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%ld %ld\n", i, fib(i));
}
```

In order to so you will have to separate i/o (prompting user for input) from the function that implements the Fibonacci algorithm.  This is a good design practice in general.  You can build two programs (one interactive and one not), or a single program and for instance drive that with a command line argument:

```
int main(int argv, char argv[]) {
    if(argc == 2) {
        long n = atol(argv[1]);
        for(long i = 0; i < n; i++)
            printf("%ld %ld\n", i, fib(i));
        return 0;
    }
    printf("n? ");
    long n;
    if(scanf("%ld", &n) != 1) return 1;
    printf("%ld %ld\n", n, fib(n));
}
```

I suggest you print the data then redirect the stdout to a file.  You will have to show us some code to figure out why your text output file feature is not working.